# How to move text beneath an Image?

Tags: html, css, image, text, margin

how can I move the text under the image to the right side of it?
I am struggleing getting this text aligned to the side. 
Hey guys, how can I move the text under the image to the right side of it?
I am struggleing getting this text aligned to the side.

```css
#main leftbar posts {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: justify;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

#main leftbar img {
    display: inline;
    height: 250px;
    margin-left: 18px;
    margin-top: 17px;
    border: solid black 1px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px -3px;
}

#main leftbar p {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-left: 300px;
    border-left: solid 5px black;
    padding-left: 6px;
}
```

```html
<main id="main">
  <leftbar>
    <posts>
      <post1>
        <a url href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
          <p>sdjksahdkjhajks dhjaskhdkjahs dsajhdka dashjdkahd  ahdjskadhka dashjdkahsdjk dasjdhkalhdjkad 
ashjdkalhdjka  sdashdjakhdlka dashdjkahdskjas 
dashjdkashdklas dasjkdhaksdl.
          </p>
      </post1>
    </posts>
  </leftbar>
</main>
```

Comment: ?? your snippet seems to show the text  under the image and the far right ? isn't ? what is the final result expected ? 100% width of the page for the container no matter the width, is image always the same size, anything else around image and text, .. ? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add `float: left` to your image:

```
#main leftbar img {
    float: left;
}
```

And add `display:block` (default) to your paragraph.

```
#main leftbar p {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#main leftbar img {
    float: left;
}
```

and

```
#main leftbar p {
    margin-left: 300px;
    border-left: solid 5px black;
    padding-left: 6px;
}
```

P element is a text element cause, so is allways inline. The trick above should do it!!

Answer (score 0):

As armin said, You can add `float: left` to your image:

```
#main leftbar img {
    float: left;
}
```

And add `display:block` (default) to your paragraph.

```
#main leftbar p {
    display: block;
}
```

But don't forget to add width on leftbar img

```
#main leftbar img {
    display: inline;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    margin-left: 18px;
    margin-top: 17px;
    border: solid black 1px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px -3px;
    float: left;
}
```

it will keep your images on a fixed div.even if you place bigger width images then 300px. it won't ruin your paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure i understood your problem, but if p remains a block it will stay under image.
You can use padding to push text and a background-gradient to draw a border. (it can be mixed with bg-color and bg-image)

```css
#main leftbar posts {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: justify;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

#main leftbar img {
    display: inline;
    height: 250px;
    width:250px;
    margin-left: 18px;
    margin-top: 17px;
    border: solid black 1px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px -3px;
}

#main leftbar p {
padding-left: 306px;
background:linear-gradient(to right,transparent 297px, black 297px, black 300px, transparent 300px);
}
```

```html
<main id="main">
  <leftbar>
    <posts>
      <post1>
        <a url href="#"><img      src="Pictures/Bleiben%20wer%20wir%20sind.jpg"></a>
          <p>sdjksahdkjhajks dhjaskhdkjahs dsajhdka dashjdkahd  ahdjskadhka dashjdkahsdjk dasjdhkalhdjkad 
ashjdkalhdjka  sdashdjakhdlka dashdjkahdskjas 
dashjdkashdklas dasjkdhaksdl.
          </p>
      </post1>
    </posts>
  </leftbar>
</main>
```

same snippet with ackground image and color too :

```css
#main leftbar posts {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: justify;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background:
linear-gradient(to right,transparent 297px, black 297px, black 300px, rgba(255, 255, 00,0.25) 300px), linear-gradient(to bottom,gray 297px, black 297px, black 300px, rgba(217, 253, 59,0.5) 300px);
    
}

#main leftbar img {
    display: inline;
    height: 250px;
    width:250px;
    margin-left: 18px;
    margin-top: 17px;
    border: solid black 1px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px -3px;
}

#main leftbar p {
margin-top:26px;
padding-left: 306px;
background:
linear-gradient(to right,transparent 297px, black 297px, black 300px, rgba(217, 253, 59,0.5) 300px), 
url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/200/) no-repeat  300px 0
;
}
```

```html
<main id="main">
  <leftbar>
    <posts>
      <post1>
        <a url href="#"><img      src="Pictures/Bleiben%20wer%20wir%20sind.jpg"></a>
          <p>sdjksahdkjhajks dhjaskhdkjahs dsajhdka dashjdkahd  ahdjskadhka dashjdkahsdjk dasjdhkalhdjkad 
ashjdkalhdjka  sdashdjakhdlka dashdjkahdskjas 
dashjdkashdklas dasjkdhaksdl.
          </p>
      </post1>
    </posts>
  </leftbar>
</main>
```